# Obtain stream format from AVPlayer Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer

May someone of you know if it's possible to obtain the stream format from the current playing item through AVPlayer? I would need to observe if it's: mpeg4, HLS, flv or whatever.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what ending does the player video link has. The correct way is to check the manifest which you can find with a proxy. But for the easiest way if your link is .m3u8 it's HLS.
Now to get the codec that the video has you need to get the manifest from the response of the .m3u8.